# Bulk Merging/Transposing Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Brand new to R, so I'm not really sure how to ask this question.

I am loading around 50 html tables, trying to get them into one data frame or data table. Each table represents 5 years worth of a single measurement for each of the 50 US states. Each state has a single row, with the following columns:

```
colnames(df) <- c("State", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013")
```

I'm currently loading each of these tables into their own data frame, so I have one data frame for each measure. I'd like to merge these all into a single data frame with one row per State/Year, with 50 additional columns (one for each of my measures). For example:

```
colnames(df) <- c("State", "Year", "Measure1", "Measure2",...,"Measure50")
```

In the interest of actually learning the language, I'm sure there's a way to do this other than manually copying each column one by one into a row of the data frame, 50x5 years.

How should I approach this problem? I'm not even sure what concepts I should be looking up (merge, melt, reshape, something else?). Should I be using data.table instead of data.frame?

**Edit with Solution:**

I was able to solve this myself by going back to the start by first constructing a 2-column data table with a row for each State/Year combination. Then as I load each of the 50 data sets, I do the following:

```
dt <- melt(dt, id.vars=c("State"))
colnames(dt) <- c("State", "Year", measureName)
setkeyv(dt, c("State", "Year"))
destination <- merge(destination, dt)
```

In essence I'm transposing each data set as I load it, giving me a layout identical to the initial data table I created, then merge the two together.

Comment: Save all you tables in one directory and then use `list.files` and `lapply` to pull them all at once into a **single** list. This should be a matter of 2-3 lines. Then use `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package to get them all into one `data.table`. **Don't** load each data set into its own `data.frame` in the global environment.

Comment: I'm doing all this in a function, so the data frames I'm creating are temporary. The function also does various other cleanup steps on the data frame its building before adding it to the final.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and show your expected output.

Comment: sounds like reshaping, not transposing. Anyway, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Not tested: 

#I assume you have tables in data frame, called this as DF1..DF50. 
#Reshape each data  
#list of all raw dataframes
DF<-as.list(paste0("DF",1:50))
#Reshape the data 
library(tidyr) # need for gather function
RDF<-do.call(cbind,lapply(1:50, function(i) {
             gather(get(DF[[i]]),State, Measure, 2001:2005)}))
#In RDF, we have repeated columns of State from each dataframe. We will keep only the first one 
RDF[grep("State",names(RDF)[-1],value=TRUE)]<-NULL
#In RDF, we have repeated columns of same variable Measure, we will rename it as Measure1 ..Measure 50
names(RDF)[2:ncol(RDF)]<-paste0("Measures",1:50)
```